# Timer going into negatives/not reseting

Tags: ios, swift, timer, counter, countdown

I am trying to set a countdown timer for my app. My code works so that every time the image whiteDot is dragged and containing smallDot the countdown begins, and smallDot is spawned in a random position on screen. I have a couple questions

1.) I am trying to get the timer to reset to 2 seconds after every time the "if (whiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil)" statement is executed.

2.) Everytime the "if" statement is executed once, it counts down normally, but when it is executed again before the countdown hits zero, it starts going into negative numbers and counting faster than 1 second.

```
import UIKit

var timeClock =  2

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

func startTimer() {
    timeClock -= 1
    time.text =  "Time: " + String(timeClock)

if whiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && timeClock > 0 {
        timeClock = 2
    }

   else if timeClock == 0 || timeClock < 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
  } 
 }

var timer = Timer()

@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    if (whiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil) {
        addOne += 1

        score.text = "\(addOne)"

        smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition()

timeClock = 2
        if timeClock == 0 || timeClock < 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        else if timeClock > 0 && (whiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame)){
            timeClock = 2

        }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)  
    }
    }
```

Comment: I might not initialize timer right off (var timer:Timer!). The timer code, if I understand it right, gets thrown on another thread with a callback after the time needed happens. So one thing I don't see in here is invalidating your timer, which is important to do. If you need to have timers fire with different durations, I would maybe make a function that takes a timerInterval as an argument and do the following steps: 1) invalidate  previous timer 2) spawn new timer with passed duration.

Comment: Please explain the intent of your code a little more? As-is, I'm wondering about a couple of things.

Comment: Specifically, your code is going to see the action routine called about once per second. 

1. Is the problem you describe that you want to constrain timeClock to be positive? 
2. I don't see anywhere you reset the value of timeClock, so it's going to count down indefinitely. Is this not what you're being?

You could do one of a couple of things:

1. You could terminate the timer when timeClock gets to zero
2. You could reset timeClock to some positive value when it goes negative

More info?

Comment: I just updated my code and added more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out my problem. I wasn't reseting the timer the timer at all. First I was trying to reset it in the 'action' function, but I just had to move it down to the bottom if statement to solve all of my problems. This code works for anybody who is trying to reset their timer when ever a certain action occurs.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController
{
 var addOne = 0

func startTimer() {

    timeClock -= 1

    time.text =  "Time: " + String(timeClock)

   if timeClock <= 0 {
    timer.invalidate()
    //show game over
    }
}

func resetTimer() {
    timer.invalidate()
    timeClock = 3
}
var timer = Timer()

 @IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    if (whiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil) {
        addOne += 1

  score.text = "\(addOne)"

        resetTimer()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(SecondViewController.startTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition()   
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var timeClock =  2
> ```

Since this appears within a class but outside of any method, this line declares a property for your class called `timeClock` and initialises it to `2`.  That will be the starting value for the `timeClock` property for any instance of that class you create.

You correctly update this value when you are counting down, but nowhere do you reset it to `2`.  Putting the property declaration lower than the `action()` method doesn't mean that it gets executed afterwards.  The property is only initialised once per instance.

What you want to do is either set the value of `timeClock` to `2` before you schedule the timer, or set it to `2` after you invalidate the timer.  Either way, you need to reset it to `2` somewhere.

Comment: I just updated my code and set timeClock = 2. Also I tried reseting it in the "else if" statement. I am still having the problem where when the "if" statement is executed once and the countdown starts, and it is executed again before the countdown hits zero, the countdown doesn't invalidate, and the numbers start going into the negatives (also start counting down at a random pace that is not a second)